# How to limit docker image's network usage or bandwidth?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

How to limit a container's network usage or bandwidth?

I searched the Internet but it seems no existing mature solutions.

I can modify the host, but cannot modify the program running in docker or docker itself. It means I can change the configurations, but not the *code* of docker that I need to re-build/re-compile.

Comment: Are you running your containers in a k8s cluster?

Comment: Yes. It is. @Yuankun

Comment: Container is no more no less a process. How would you limit process' bandwidth usage?

Comment: I have had success doing this with TC on the container though today I would use the k8s plugin

Comment: @emix you give that process access to a virtual network interface and use something like TC to shape it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes now has an experimental feature that enables limiting network bandwidth:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#support-traffic-shaping

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth: 1M
    kubernetes.io/egress-bandwidth: 1M
```

Answer (score 5):

[Docker issue 9607](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9607) refers to [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/), and [issue 4763](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4763) is still opened.

So this is not yet natively supported by docker.

[Kubernetes issue 2856](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2856) references a [sidecar option: istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting.html), so that would be your best approach, if you can add an orchestrator to your current docker setup.